# Orthogonal matrix and trigonometric functions of matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization, symmetric-matrices, orthogonal-matrices

Let me try to summarize my question by taking into consideration some elementary notions of orthogonal matrices.

The general $2\times2$ orthogonal matrix has the form:

$$O = \begin{pmatrix} \cos\theta & \sin\theta \\ -\sin\theta & \cos\theta  \end{pmatrix} $$

Where $\theta$ is an arbitrary real number. It follows that $O^T O = I$. This matrix is also capable of diagonalizing some symmetric matrix $A$:

$$O^T A O = \text{diag}(A)$$

Now, let's assume that $\theta$ is not a real number, but rather, is a matrix. Therefore:

$$O^T O = \begin{pmatrix}\cos\theta^T \cos\theta + \sin\theta^T \sin\theta & \cos\theta^T\sin\theta - \sin\theta^T\cos\theta \\ -\sin\theta^T\cos\theta + \cos\theta^T\sin\theta & \cos\theta^T\cos\theta + \sin\theta^T\sin\theta   \end{pmatrix}$$

It is no longer clear that $O^T O$ is the identity. It actually seems like:

$$O^\prime = \begin{pmatrix}\cos\theta & -\sin\theta \\ \sin\theta & \cos\theta  \end{pmatrix}$$

is the inverse of $O$ instead of $O^T$. Moreover, there also seems to be an issue with the diagonalization of our matrix $A$, it seems like $O^T A O$ would no longer yield a diagonal matrix because $O$ and $O^T$ are no longer the inverse of each other (maybe I am wrong with my reasoning?), but if I use $O^\prime A O$ instead, there is still an issue since it would seem as if the diagonal matrix is not symmetric, and, therefore, can't be diagonal.

Is this generalization completely nonsensical or am I missing something here?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by the cos or sin of a matrix?

Comment: Also, your first statement is not quite correct. There are also orthogonal matrices of the form 
$$
\pmatrix{\cos \theta & \sin \theta \\ \sin \theta & - \cos \theta}.
$$

Comment: @BenGrossmann the usual way I interpret it is as a Fourier Series: $\cos\theta = 1 - \frac{1}{2} \theta^2 + \dots$ and $\sin\theta = \theta - \frac{1}{3!} \theta^3 + \dots$

Comment: @BenGrossmann, oh sorry, I have been only dealing with rotation matrices, but you're right in that manner, I was not considering that type of matrices.

Comment: So in this context, $\theta$ is necessarily a square matrix. Is that correct to assume?

Comment: @BenGrossmann, yes, $\theta$ should be a square matrix

Comment: It might be interesting to note that this process **does** produce an orthogonal matrix if $\theta$ is a symmetric matrix.

Comment: Some of your analysis is incorrect. The fact that $O^T \neq O^{-1}$ does not imply that $O^TAO$ **cannot** be diagonal, as you have indicated. Similarly, the fact that $O' \neq O^T$ does not imply that $O'AO$ **cannot** be diagonal.